jsforce logout not working properly
router.get("/logout", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const conn = new Connection({
      oauth2: oauth2,
      instanceUrl: req.session.instanceUrl,
      accessToken: req.session.accessToken,
      refreshToken: req.session.refreshToken,
    });

    await conn.logout(true, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("|error|", err);
      }
    });
    req.session.destroy();
    res.clearCookie(process.env.COOKIE_NAME);
    return res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      message: "Logout complete",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      error: error.message,
    });
  }
});

This is logging me out of the app and invalidating the tokens, however whenever I am trying to relogin using
      oauth2.getAuthorizationUrl({
        scope: "api web id refresh_token offline_access",
      });

It redirects me to the instance url of the previous org and automatically reauthenticates without asking for credentials. How can I prevent this ?
